# Bandwidth limits for different SSIDs

Tags: router, wireless

I have basic understanding of networking, switching, and routing and am trying to set up D-Link  DWL-3200AP with two SSIDs, each with its own data rate limit.  I have two SSIDs working however, can't seem to figure out how to add individual bandwidth limits.  Is this even possible?

ASCII art diagram:

```
[ Netgear CG3000DCR Cable Modem/Wired Router ] <====> [ D-Link DWL-3200AP ]
```

Comment: I believe I understand the thinking behind the Close votes, however, the kind of "Prosumer" networking gear referenced in this question [is explicitly on topic](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) per the current guidelines.  If there are feelings that it should not be, then please take it up in [Meta](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Unfortunately with your current equipment you're out of luck.

**Long answer:**

From what I'm seeing on [D-Link's website for the DWL-3200AP](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/business-solutions/wireless/access-points/access-points/dwl-3200ap-wireless-poe-access-point), this AP is pretty basic and does not support the type of QOS functionality you're looking for.

Also in looking at the Tech Specs on [Netgear's website for the CG3000DCR](http://www.netgear.com/service-providers/products/cable/gateways/cg3000dcr.aspx#tab-techspecs), you're utilizing a very basic combo Modem/Router.

As other folks on this site have pointed out, this type of equipment falls into the *"Pro-sumer"* niche.  While these devices are on topic for this site, and are arguably more powerful/feature rich than normal consumer gear, they fall very short of "Enterprise grade".  So as your needs increase for network segmentation, QOS, and any other dozen features, you will begin to feel the hurt from these devices.

If this is a feature your business needs, you may want to look into putting a more powerful/feature rich network and wireless solution in place.

Comment: The modem/router is Netgear CG3000DCR.

Comment: @or2well I've added this info to the original question and updated my answer as well.